# Git how to exit rebase mode

Tags: git

I did a Git rebase, fixed the conflict and force pushed already, why it is still rebase mode, "dev|REBASE 2/3" ? how to exit it ? I don't want to throw away the rebase.

```
aaa@lenovo-pc MINGW64 ~/Documents/NetBeansProjects/GitTest1 (dev|REBASE 2/3)
$ git status
rebase in progress; onto f67f4c5
You are currently rebasing branch 'dev' on 'f67f4c5'.
  (all conflicts fixed: run "git rebase --continue")

nothing to commit, working tree clean

aaa@lenovo-pc MINGW64 ~/Documents/NetBeansProjects/GitTest1 (dev|REBASE 2/3)
$ git push --force origin dev
git@192.168.1.8's password:
Everything up-to-date

aaa@lenovo-pc MINGW64 ~/Documents/NetBeansProjects/GitTest1 (dev|REBASE 2/3)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 80):

```
git rebase --abort
```

this should do the trick for you.

UPD:

git rebase is somewhat "atomic" operation. You cannot finish it in the middle. Think of it as of the transaction. It either finishes or not. If you think that you're finished, but your working copy is still in "rebase" mode than means you've done something wrong, i.e.:

- Manually added the commit with `git commit`
- Didn't resolve the conflict if that was the case. Usually rebase is an automatic operation that you just run and watch, it stops only when the conflict is not resolved.

How to resolve a conflict? Well, that is a good separate question.

Comment: it will revert back my changes ?

Comment: Yes. I will expand the answer for you.

Comment: `git rebase --quit` also works, with jumping out of current branch.

Comment: I love your answer @NickTsai . In my case, I working on older project, and suddenly I'm in "rebase mode". Idk what happened in previous, so I did your answer and I can working like usual

Answer (score 1):

I have generally found that simply following the instructions which prompts to you during the rebase process usually doesn't go wrong.  Based on the snippet you showed us, which says:

```
(all conflicts fixed: run "git rebase --continue")
```

your next move probably should have been to run `git rebase --continue` to finish the rebase, or at least move to the next applied commit.

**What to do now:**

Instead of completing/continuing with the rebase, you force pushed the `dev` branch to the remote.  Since you would likely have to force push this anyway after the rebase, I don't see any long term harm being done.  So you should just complete the rebase by doing

```
git rebase --continue
```

and then force push again once the rebase is actually completed.

By the way, if you decide that you really want to throw away the rebase, you can do so via

```
git rebase --abort
```

Comment: I don't want to throw away the rebase. how to exit ? use --continue, doesn't help

Comment: @user1615666 Then do git rebase --abort and start over

Answer (score 0):

You can exit from rebase mode by the following command `git rebase --abort`